# Windows Phone 7.1 - How to change background image on button press?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

How do I change the background image of some canvas from withing the c# code on button press? I know how to change the background color:

```
Canvas1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

I found a tutorial online , but VS says that "The type or namespace name 'BitmapImage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
 var brush = new ImageBrush();
 brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/myImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
 Canvas1.Background = brush;
```

What am I missing?

TIA!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a reference to the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace. Add this to the top of your class, where the other `using directives` are.

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```